# Makefile that generates executables that run Node scripts

Tags: node.js, bash, unix, makefile, executable

How can I make a **Makefile** that will generate an executable, say `myscript` for example, which translates to the following:

```
node myscript.js param1
```

So all I have to run is

```
myscript param1
```

Comment: Create a C script that does `system` on `node myscript.js` with arguments. Shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it generate a file with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

node myscript.js "$@"
```

And then have it mark the file executable (`chmod +x myscript`).

Comment: How do you get it to generate a file with specific contents?

Comment: That would be a silly thing to do. Just create the file outside.

Comment: I have `all:
 echo 'node gbnSender.js "$@"' > gbnSender
 chmod +x gbnSender` which makes the file `gbnSender` but I can't run it from the Terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try specifying the path, e.g. `./gbnSender`?

Comment: That works, but I need to be able to run it with `gbnSender <params>`. The file also isn't getting the params. Here are the contents of the generated `gbnSender` file: `node gbnSender.js "all"`. This is after running `make`, `make all`, `make Makefile all`, or `make all Makefile`. How can I get it to use the arguments when I run it later instead of when I `make` it?